# microsoft visual c++ 2015 redistributable is not installing

Tags: windows, visual-c++

when i try to install microsoft visual c++ 2015 in my pc , it shows " one or more issues caused the setup to fail. please fix the issues and then retry setup. for more information see the log file.

0x80240017- Unspecified error"

how to solve the issues?

Answer (score 0):

The following Microsoft article may be helpful: [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (0x80240017) - Unspecified error](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/microsoft-visual-c-2015-redistributable-0x80240017/096734b6-9923-40c9-8722-cfe5e73d31a6)

As the article notes, you may check **Windows Update Troubleshooter** for problems, as well as trying to install in **Safe Mode**.